# Make safari open new tab from context menu in background

Tags: macos, safari

In Mac OS Safari, when we select a word, open the context menu and run 'Search with google', the result comes in a new tab and it becomes the active tab automatically. Is there someway for that tab to open in background?

[image: In Mac OS Safari, when we select a word, open the context menu and run 'Search with google', the result comes in a new tab and it becomes the active tab automatically. Is there someway for that tab to open in background ?]

There is an option in tab preferences but that doesnt apply to tabs opened from context menu.